# numpy apply_along_axis with different result size

Tags: python, numpy

I've a function that is returning a subset of a column, and I'd like to efficiently apply it to each column. So the result is not a matrix anymore but a list of column of different length. I've failed to use numpy `apply_along_axis` to do so because of this size mismatch. Is there a way to do so efficiently, other than iterating through the column  myself?

```
col_pred = lambda x: [v for v in x if v > 0.5]
filteredData = np.apply_along_axis(col_pred, 0, data)
# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (4)
```

for instance with an input

```
data = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
// my real data is more like a matrix with a lot of rows in [0-1]
// that can be simulated with 
// data = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(10)] for j in range(100000)]
```

I'd like to get

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Give us a sample input data to work with and show us the expected output?

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question

Comment: I am guessing that a bit over-simplistic sample, as you have `v > 0.5` in the codes. Or do you actually have only 1s and 0s in the data?

Comment: Yes I've values in [0-1] that are coming from predictions

Comment: `apply_along_axis` just makes some kinds of iteration simpler, not faster.  So if it doesn't suit your job don't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems you are trying to output all elements per column that are greater than a threshold `0.5`. Here's an approach to fulfil those and also generalized to handle those both along the rows and columns -

```
def threshold_along_an_axis(a, thresh = 0.5, axis=0):
    if axis==0:
        A = a.T
    else:
        A = a
    mask = A>thresh
    s = mask.sum(1)
    s0 = np.r_[0,s.cumsum()]
    arr = A[mask].tolist() # Skip .tolist() if list of arrays is needed as o/p
    return [arr[s0[i]:s0[i+1]] for i in range(len(s0)-1)]
```

The intention here is to do minimal work inside the loop comprehension.

Sample run -

```
In [1]: a = np.random.rand(4,5)

In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.45973245,  0.3671334 ,  0.12000436,  0.04205402,  0.74729737],
       [ 0.55217308,  0.4018889 ,  0.55695863,  0.55824384,  0.33435153],
       [ 0.32450124,  0.07713855,  0.09126221,  0.13150986,  0.27961361],
       [ 0.0876053 ,  0.42685005,  0.53034652,  0.15084453,  0.51518185]])

In [3]: threshold_along_an_axis(a, thresh=0.5, axis=0) # per column
Out[3]: 
[[0.5521730819881912],
 [],
 [0.5569586261866918, 0.5303465159370833],
 [0.5582438446718111],
 [0.7472973699509776, 0.5151818458812673]]

In [4]: threshold_along_an_axis(a, thresh=0.5, axis=1) # per row
Out[4]: 
[[0.7472973699509776],
 [0.5521730819881912, 0.5569586261866918, 0.5582438446718111],
 [],
 [0.5303465159370833, 0.5151818458812673]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that looks great

Comment: @Guig Remember to use something like `np.random.rand(4,5)` to create the input data/array, should be really efficient, than `[[random....` way.

Comment: Yep. As I mentioned to @hpaulj this was just an example of the type of input data I'm expecting. The real data is coming from a larger machine learning prediction pipeline and outputs probabilities. I'll keep that in mind anyway.

Comment: @Guig Awesome! Then, we can just focus on grouping elements, nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ragged array in numpy, you have to use object arrays.

You first need a small helper function to convert any value into a 0d object array:

```
def object_scalar(x):
    obj = np.empty((), dtype=object)
    obj[()] = x
    return obj
```

Then, in the upcoming 1.13, you can do:

```
>>> f = lambda x: object_scalar(col_pred(x))
>>> np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, data)
array([list([1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1])], dtype=object)
```

Unfortunately, the latest *released* version of numpy has a bug that makes `apply_along_axis` not handle 0d arrays correctly. You can work around that by promoting to a 1d array, and then demoting back to 0d afterwards:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: f(x)[np.newaxis], 0, data).squeeze(axis=0)
array([[1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a sense of the overhead due to the reshaping? Doesn't sounds like much and I'll time it but just checking.

Comment: @Guig: Creating the new object array each time is where most of the cost goes to, sadly - this solution isn't going to win on performance on any existing numpy version. `.squeeze`, at least, is essentially free.

Answer (score 1):

So as a Python list problem this is:

```
In [606]: col_pred = lambda x: [v for v in x if v > 0.5]
In [607]: data = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
In [608]: [col_pred(i) for i in data]
Out[608]: [[1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

In your big data example, it takes much longer to generate the data than to run this list comprehension:

```
In [611]: data1 = [[np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(10)] for j in range(100000)]
In [612]: timeit data1 = [[np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(10)] for j in range(100000)]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.62 s per loop

In [615]: data2=[col_pred(i) for i in data1]
In [618]: timeit data2=[col_pred(i) for i in data1]
10 loops, best of 3: 191 ms per loop
```

Comparing this with `@Divakar's efficient numpy solution

```
In [622]: threshold_along_an_axis(np.array(data).T)
Out[622]: [[1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
In [624]: x3=threshold_along_an_axis(np.array(data1).T)
In [625]: timeit x3=threshold_along_an_axis(np.array(data1).T)
10 loops, best of 3: 214 ms per loop
```

Oops - it's slower; unless we take the array creation step out of the timing:

```
In [626]: arr=np.array(data1).T
In [627]: timeit x3=threshold_along_an_axis(arr)
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop
```

This an old familiar story.  List comprehensions often perform well for small lists and when array creation adds significant overhead.

I don't have 1.13 and the new stuff that Eric mentions, but changing the list to a object array does let me use `np.frompyfunc`:

```
In [640]: dataO = np.empty(len(data1), object)
In [641]: dataO[:]=data1
In [642]: x5=np.frompyfunc(col_pred, 1,1)(dataO)
In [643]: timeit x5=np.frompyfunc(col_pred, 1,1)(dataO)
10 loops, best of 3: 197 ms per loop
```

`np.frompyfunc` takes an array (or arrays) applies broadcasting and evaluates a 'scalar' function, returning an object array.  It is used by `np.vectorize`, and often gives a 2x speed improvement over direct iteration.  Here, though, it does not help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for going in the details. I should have specified that the data creation is not part of the problem since it's coming from a much larger machine learning prediction pipeline. I put is there as an example of the input data I'm trying to process. Still very interesting.

Comment: However they are generated,it seems to me that this compression step is a relatively minor one.  But that random array could be generated with one call: `xr=np.random.uniform(0,1,(100000,10))`.